# Visual Studio 2008 ClickOnce cannot find exe in obj\Release

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

Project Output Path of the the main application is set to ......\bin\Release\ and was  published flawlessly by ClickOnce before.  For some strange reason, ClickOnce now fails with the following error:

```
Could not find file 'obj\Release\EMS.OCC600.Infrastructure.Shell.exe'.
    c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets
    2341     9     Infrastructure.Shell
```

Anyone run into this before?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but have you done a Clean Solution recently?
Try a full Rebuild Solution then try to publish again. Make sure the obj/Release dir contains your exe file.